# Laravel: the Create Method gives an 404!! don't know why

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find the problem it gave me an 404 not found!!

Routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/companies/{company}/services/create', 'Admin\ServicesController@create')->name('services.create');
```

Controller:

```
  *
 * @param $company
 * @return Factory|View
 */
public function create($company){
    $company=Company::where('id','=',$company)->findOrFail($company);



    return view('admin.services.create',compact('company'));

}
```

View:

```
    <a href="{{ route('services.create',['company'=>$company->id]) }}" class="btn btn-success my-5"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New Service</a>
```

URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/companies/1/services/create

Comment: either use where or findorfail dont use both

Comment: findorfail always give 404 if id is not found in the database.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit i've changed the code but still giving 404

Comment: is .htaccess is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your controller this way:

```
public function create($company){
    $company=Company::where('id','=',$company)->first();
    return view('admin.services.create',compact('company'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function create($company)
{
  $company=Company::where('id','=',$company)->first();
  return view('admin.services.create',compact('company'));
}
```

In view

```
@forelse($company as $company)
  {{$company}}
@empty  //empty check
  {{No details found}}
@endforelse
```